# disable fail2ban email notifications on a service?

Tags: fail2ban, ubuntu-18.04

Is there a way to continue to have Fail2Ban send email notification but disable it for an individual service? I keep getting 100 alerts on sshd and I would like to disable email notifications for sshd and everything else to still send email notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://blog.wturrell.co.uk/how-to-turn-off-fail2ban-email-notifications/

> In /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` there’s a section that describes various
> actions – look for action_, action_mw and action_mwl.  You’ll see they
> vary in scope, from just writing to the logfile to emailing the
> sysadmin (or even administrators identified in whois lookups) or
> automatically banning IPs from 3rd-party services like CloudFlare.
>
> Further down is this:
>
> ## Choose default action.  To change, just override value of 'action' with the
>
> ## interpolation to the chosen action shortcut (e.g.  action_mw, action_mwl, etc) in jail.local
>
> ## globally (section [DEFAULT]) or per specific section action = %(action_)s
>
> In other words, you can have a single definition in
> /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf and reuse it in jail.local without writing it
> out again in full.  It will need to go in the correct [section] (or
> “jail”) or under [DEFAULT].

Remember to restart the service afterwards!